# how to convert PDT/PST time to oracle standard format?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a requirement that. Have to convert the date which is in the format below

Fri Dec 7 15:14:31 PDT 2007

to oracle standard format(DD-MON-YY) using sql/plsql

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: There is no Oracle standard format and a date has no format. I'm afraid it's not really clear what you are doing or why? Are you displaying data in an application or attempting to store it in the database?

Comment: in my table one blob file is there in that the date is in the above format 'Fri Dec 7 15:14:31 PDT 2007' i want to store it into another table column datatype is date

Comment: Converting a string to a date is easy (see my answer).  But the phrase "blob file" concerns me.  Getting info from a binary format into test can be tricky.  You need to provide more details.  If you want people to spend *their time* helping you, you should invest *your time* in framing the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert a string to a timestamp datatype using the TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ function.  Because you have a complicated string you must ensure you get the format mask right ([find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079)).

```
select to_timestamp_tz (
     'Fri Dec 7 15:14:31 PDT 2007'
     , 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY' ) as ts
from dual
/
```

If you want to store that in a date column Oracle will handle the casting implicitly or you can choose to be explicit....

```
cast (to_timestamp_tz (
     'Fri Dec 7 15:14:31 PDT 2007'
     , 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY' ) 
     as date )
```

If this is just about display use the TO_CHAR function on the timestamp with the required mask, 'DD-MON-YYYY'.